# Laravel default user_id attribute in Model

Tags: laravel-5

I have a model

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id'
    ];

}
```

I would like to set `Auth::user()->id` by default to `user_id` column. So I added:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function setUserIdAttribute()
    {
        $this->attributes['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

    }
}
```

And from my controller I'm calling for `Foo::create($data)` without `user_id` key.
But it doesn't work as expected. `store()` gives `Integrity constraint violation` because of `user_id` is missing. (User already logged in to achieve create page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You provide an example where you used accessors.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

From official doc:

> The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value of first_name:

If you want to set default value for some attributes you need to use Observers.

```
<?php
// file app/models/Foo.php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Observers\FooObserver;

class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        parent::observe(new FooObserver);
    }
}

<?php
// file app/observers/FooObserver.php
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Foo;

class FooObserver {

    public function creating(Foo $model) {
        $this->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }
}
```

About model observers in official doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers

Answer (score 5):

i cannot find official documentation about `model-observers` for Laravel 5.6. but you can still do it by this code

```
public static  function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    // it will automatically add authenticate user to created_by column of selected model 
    static::creating(function ($model){
        $model->created_by = auth()->user()->id;
    });
}
```